# Web browser plugin for bulk domain

Tags: google-chrome, web, firefox, plugins

I managed school websites which around 100 domains.
My boss asking me what is an easy way for him to get and see front page for all the website on the different domain.

Is there any web browser plugin can solve this?

This will be easy if I can give him domain.txt and plugin will do the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, just navigate to 100 different urls? Does it have to open all pages at once? Does it have to have a GUI? Is a CLI method ok? Please precise your question - as of now, it is too broad.

Comment: @NinoFiliu Asking for off-site tools/resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this server-sided:

- Create a scripted page, that uses `iframe`s to show a tiled view of the target pages
- Make this script configurable via a `domains.txt`, a database or whatever works best for you
- Point your boss to tis page